# Opening another form in a form (schoolproject)

Tags: c#

This is my code but I have a problem:

> an object reference is required for the nonstatic field.

In my `form1` I have a button called `btnWerknemergegevens` and I when I click on it, then I want that my 2nd form `frmWerknemergegevens` to show.

Here's my code so far:

```
namespace SanderHoskens_GIP
{
    public partial class frmStartmenu : Form
    {
       public frmStartmenu()
       {

       }

       private void btnWerknemergegevens_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
            frmWerknemergegevens.Show();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: not related to opencv **at all**.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you don't have an instance of your other form. The error that you're getting explains everything perfectly. This is what you'll need to do in your `Click` method:

```
// This creates a new instance of that class.
var form = new frmWrknemergegevens();
// Call the show method on the instance, not on the class itself.
form.Show();
```

Only methods marked as `static` can be called on the class itself. Everything else needs to be run against an object of that type.